# Complex series Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find the domain of convergence of :

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in}}{(z+1)^n} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z+1)^n}{e^{\frac{1}{2}+in}}\ \ \ \ (z\in\mathbb{C})$

---

I've found that it diverges for any complex number $z$, is this correct ?

Comment: No. Can you see that it converges for $z=1$? Are you familiar with geometric series? with the ratio test?

Comment: I don't think it converges for $z=1$, the left sum converges but the right one diverges.
and yes I've done the ratio test and got that it diverges for all $z$.

Comment: ${1\over\sqrt e}\sum(2^n/e^n)$ diverges?

Comment: sorry, there was a typo, I've  fixed now.

Comment: All you need to know here is that the geometric series $\sum_{n\geq n_0}r^n$ converges if and only if $|r|<1$. The intersection of the two domains involved is indeed empty.

Comment: thank you julien, this is exactly what I've done, and also casework for $|r|=1$, I just wanted confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not leave this unanswered: since the terms  with base $e$ have absolute value independent of $n$, the sum of two series converges  if and only if $|z+1|>1$  and  $|z+1|<1$ hold simultaneously. Which is to say, never.